# stack is being reset after each push and shows empty message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

i have a program with 3classes.

first one is for defining a node(my node is an array with 9 elements) - 2nd one contains some functions - 3rd is defining a static stack(I have a stack with 100members that each member is an array with 9members)

suppose that in main(), I call one of the functions from 2nd class(for example expand() ). expand function is supposed to push a node into stack(push into UN) and update the stack pointer. After that for example I want to have access to top node of stack and pop that node using main(). but I'm successful. when I watch the UN and top node through debug tool, I see that their amount is being reset after each push(stack doesn't accept new elements). whats wrong?

here is some parts of code that is needed:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max 100

class node
{
public:
    int node_n[9];
    friend class func;
    friend class stack;
};
node n;

class node;
class func
{
public: 
    func();
    void expand(node,stack);
    friend class stack; 
};

class node;
class stack 
{
private:
    int sp;//stack pointer
public:
    node un[max];//saves expanded noded(children)
    stack();
    int isempty(); //this will show whether stack is empty or not
    int isfull(); //this will show whether stack is full or not
    void push(node);
    node pop();
};

//****************************
stack::stack()
{
     sp=-1;
}
//****************************
int stack::isempty()
{
    if(sp==-1) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;    
}
//****************************
int stack::isfull()
{
        return sp==max-1;
}

//****************************

node stack::pop()                 //un=un-[n]
{
    for(int k=0;k<=8;k++)
        n.node[k]=un[sp].node[k];
    sp--;
    return n;
}

//****************************
void stack::push(node n )            //un=un+{x1....xn}
{
    sp++;
    for(int k=0;k<=8;k++)
        un[sp].node[k]=n.node[k];
}

//****************************
void func::expand(node n,stack st)
{
    if ( n.node_n[0]==0 )
    {
        if(n.node_n[1]==0)
        {
            n.node_n[0]=1;
            n.node_n[1]=1;
            st.push(n); 
        .
        .
        .
//******************************
int main()
{
    func b;
    stack st;
    node n2;
    node s; //initial state
    node g; //goal state

    for(int h=0;h<=8;h++)
    {
        s.node[h]=0;
        g.node[h]=1;
    }

    //n2=s;
    st.push(s);

Lable1:
    n2=st.pop();
    b.expand(n2,st);
    goto Lable1;

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: That's a job for your debugger, not to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have checked debugger and I saw that is it not working properly and since I'm new to programming I thought maybe I have problem in code.

Comment: So what did you observe, when stepping through your code with the debugger? What's actually _not working properly_?

Comment: when I push the node into my stack( UN), the first member of the stack, gets the node. but then when I want to reach the top of stack and remove it using the pop function, I see that stack is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

```
void func::expand(node n,stack st)
```

is taking the `st` parameter by value, meaning that it has its own copy of `st` and any changes it makes will only affect that copy.

What you probably want is to pass `st` by reference, so that the function can make changes to the original passed in object. To do this, change the function declaration and definition to:

```
void func::expand(node n,stack &st)
```

Comment: tnx. ur answer helped me a lot